# Is this n plus 1 problem? Multiple DbContext call in single request

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm not sure I fully understand the n+1 problem. Does this case also relate to the  n+1 problem?

Using EF Core: for example there are 10000 members and 1000000 transactions.

```cs
public class ReportService
{
      ...
      public IEnumerbale<ReportItem> GetResult()
      {
           var reportItems = new List<ReportItem>();
           var members = _context.Users.Where(x => x.IsMember);

           foreach(var member in members)
           {
               var calculationResult = _calculationService.Calculate(member.Id);
               reportItems.Add(calculationResult); 
           }

           return reportItems;
      }
}

public class CalculationService
{
      ...
      public CalculationResult Calculate(int memberId)
      {
           var memberTransactions = _context.Transactions.Where(x => x.UserId == memberId);

           var result = new CalculationResult(memberTransactions.Sum(x => x.Amount));

           return result;
      }
}
```

Should I move responsibility to get data from the `CalculationService` (to avoid many queries)? What is the best way to avoid situations like this one?

Answer (score 0):

Finding users and than making a foreach to finding each users Transaction data will make a lot of effort and may kill your perfomance.
This kind of code will make you api quite slow and it may throw time out exceptions. the better way will be   joining your both tables and just getting result from joined list. Something like this will be better.

```
context.Users.Join(
contex.Transactions, 
x => x.MemberId, 
xm => xm.MemberId
(x,xm) => new {Users = x, Transactions = xm }
).Select(p => p.Transactions.Amount).Sum()
```

This will make easier for you app and you dont't need each time make a query.